# My PC switch on alone when i close the lid to let it go in stand by (after some hours)

Tags: 22.04, suspend, hibernate, lid, standby

I'm using Ubuntu 22.04 and I know closing the lid is not the best solution to put the pc in stand by, but when I do and i let it go for some hours, I find it compleatly discharge.
Last night happened that I closed the lid during the stream of a movie, and after more on less 5 hours, with the lid closed the movie played with audio too.
Thank you all for the help

Comment: I have an Acer Swift 3 SF314-511